# Customize Android Phonegap "Webpage not available" when server is down

Tags: android, cordova

When the server is down or the web link is not available, the Android system uses an error page saying : "Webpage not available"

This page is not very beautiful. Is it possible to customize this page?

It is not a connection problem. You can have Internet connection AND your server down. In that case I need to find a solution to hide this page.

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks :)

S.L.